# What's the difference between `:doautocmd` and `doautoall`?

Tags: neovim, autocmd

I'm using NeoVim and trying to understand why the need of creating `augroup`. Then I realized that I don't know the two related commands `doautoall`, `doautocmd`. Can anyone help me point out the important part I should care?

To be more specific, under `:h doautocmd`, I cannot understand this paragraph:

> When the [group] argument is not given, Vim executes
> the autocommands for all groups.  When the [group]
> argument is included, Vim executes only the matching
> autocommands for that group.  Undefined group is an
> error.

What does it mean "executes the autocommands for all groups" when these groups are `autocmd`s to execute?

---

As this is an important topic to me, I will also try to answer myself after I would figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> why the need of creating augroup.

Groups are used, well, for grouping autocmds. This is essential for managing them. If none was specified then the next autocmd will get into the default augroup.

> I don't know the two related commands doautoall, doautocmd

Basically, "doautoall" loops over all loaded buffers/windows and calls "doautocmd" repeatedly. There are several nuances, of course. E.g. no other autocmd (BufEnter, BufLeave, WinEnter, WinLeave etc.etc.) will be triggered during the loop; if a buffer has no window (not in the current tab or no window at all) then the special "autocmd" window will be used instead and so on.

> What does it mean "executes the autocommands for all groups"

If a group was specified then only autocmds from that group may be executed (the ones that match all other attributes, of course). Otherwise, it works "as normal".

Comment: @job_start Obviously, if we need it to be something other than the current buffer. There can be different events...

Comment: And more strangely, even the `fname` can just be a simple string pattern, no need to be a "file pattern" like `*.c`. But this is not documented in the docs(I've read `:h doautocmd` and `:h autocmd`, both not mentioned). Do you know why?

Comment: @job_start This is an argument passed to autocommand. Go and read about specific events if you want to know what can it be used for. There are dozens of them.

Comment: @job_start There is a difference between argument passed and pattern matched against that argument, isn't there?

Comment: @job_start "doau" accepts fname as argument; "au" accepts aupat as pattern to match against fname. What kind of inconsistency you're talking about?!

Comment: And so what? 1. Apparently, "fname" is buffer name, not really "file name". 2. The core doesn't check argument validity for you; if you wanna shoot your leg then go ahead.

Comment: So I simply meant that it can be renamed to `pattern` or something more readable. Btw, why did you know `fname` is buffer name? I thought it was file name.

Comment: Let me clean up my comments above, as I feel like understand how these things work. Sorry for asking maybe not-good questions in the comment section.

Comment: 1. For bufenter (and many others) it should be current buffer name 2. For no event it is a pattern of any kind AFAIK 3. The extra questions should be asked separately, not within comments. The moders are never happy about that.

Answer (score 0):

Q: *What does it mean "executes the autocommands for all groups" when these groups are `autocmd`s to execute?*

You can read it as "executes the autocommands **from** all groups".

---

For `doau`, it will run all matched(the optional `[fname]` argument you provided) autocmds of the specified augroup. I will show you an example.

First, open any file (in my case `git.lua`) and run the following commands:

```lua
:aug FRANK -- this creates an augroup
:au FRANK BufEnter * echo "Hi, *"
:au FRANK BufEnter *.lua echo "Hi, *.lua"
:au FRANK BufEnter git.lua echo "Hi, git.lua"
```

Then call `:h doau`, this will move your cursor to the help-docs. Now call `:doau FRANK BufEnter`, you will see:

```
hi *
```

then move your cursor to your "any file" (`git.lua` in my case) and run `:doau FRANK BufEnter` again. You will see (something similar to):

```
hi *
hi *.lua
hi git.lua
```

This proves that this line of the docs is correct (see `:h doau`):

```
Apply the autocommands matching [fname] (default:
            current file name) for {event} to the current buffer.
```

Finally, `:doautoa` will do `:doau` many times.